# Append Numpy array to correct shape

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having a very hard time appending my `x_` array to `x` while maintaining the correct shape. I tried `vstack`, but it gave me an error. The `axis=0` doesn't seem to be doing anything like it's supposed to. I want an array with dimension (`:,len(x_)`).

Edit:

The code at the end of the post gives arrays x_ of the following shape:

```
array([3, 0, 2, 1, 0], dtype=int32)
```

I tried:

```
x_ = np.append(x_,np.array([5,4,6,7,8]), axis = 0)
```

But gives:

```
array([3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8])
```

However, I want:

```
array([[3, 0, 2, 1, 0],
       [5, 4, 6, 7, 8]])
```

I tried vstack(x,x_), but got:

```
   x = np.vstack(x, x_)

TypeError: vstack() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

.

```
for k in range(2,9):
    temp_ = (2*k)+1
    x = np.zeros(shape=(1,temp_))
    y = []
    for i in range(k, len(number_list)-k-1):
        newk = k
        x_ = []
        while newk >= -k:
            x_.append(name[i-newk])
            newk-=1
        le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
        le.fit(x_)
        x_ = le.transform(x_)
        x = np.append(x, x_ , axis=0)
        y.append(residue_area[i])
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the full traceback of the error?

Comment: Please add your input data and the desired result.

Comment: Appending to a list is faster and less error prone.  But if you must join arrays, use the basic `np.concatenate`.  It requires correct array shapes, and doesn't try to compensate or second guess your intentions.

Comment: Please see the edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`np.append` must be abolished; it distorts the thinking of too many beginners.

`np.concatenate` and all the `np.?stack` take a list as the first argument.  The only other argument is an axis keyword.  `np.append` changes that convention by replacing that list with 2 arguments - which it then tweaks, puts in a list and calls concatenate.  And unless you read the source code you don't know for sure how it modifies the dimensions first.

Pull up an interactive session, and play with `np.concatenate` until you understand how the dimensions must match.  Then revisit this problem.

edit: spelling error `concatenate` instead of `concatenante`

Comment: Thanks, but one question remains. By creating a zeros array with certain shape, I have to create a zeros first entry, which I don't want. How can I create an empty array of certain shape?

Comment: If you MUST go the iterative `concatenate` route, you could start with `np.zeros(shape=(0,temp_))`.  Getting the starting array right is part of why I dislike `np.append`.  Starting a list append with `[]` is a well known Python idiom.  The numpy equivalent is awkward.  Much better to collect ALL subarrays in a list, and do `concatenate` just once.

Answer (score 2):

But you can use [`np.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x_ = np.array([3, 0, 2, 1, 0]) 
>>> x_ = np.vstack([x_, np.array([5, 4, 6, 7, 8])])
>>> x_
array([[3, 0, 2, 1, 0],
       [5, 4, 6, 7, 8]])
```

But generally it's a bad idea (because it's *really* inefficient) to append or stack arrays regularly. Often it's better to create an array of the final shape and insert into it:

```
>>> x_ = np.empty((2, 5), dtype=int)
>>> x_[0] = [3, 0, 2, 1, 0]
>>> x_[1] = [5, 4, 6, 7, 8]
>>> x_
array([[3, 0, 2, 1, 0],
       [5, 4, 6, 7, 8]])
```

Comment: Thanks, vstack worked for me, but one question remains. By creating a zeros array with certain shape, I have to create a zeros first entry, which I don't want. How can I create an empty array of certain shape?

Comment: No, don't create an empty array and append to it. Like I said that's a very inefficient solution (and I mean terrible inefficient). You can either use a normal list `[]` and append to it and convert it to an array after you finished appending or you create an empty array of the final shape and then insert into it.